# cocos2d onEnter, onExit

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, memory-management

eg)
1. When X sprite is touched, pointer of X is stored in class Y
2. when X sprite is removedFromParent, X sprite will notify Y that it's going away

How do I achieve the second step?
Specifically, onExit(of class X) is a good place to do this kind of stuff?
When does onEnter/onExit get called? I don't find the reference helpful on this.

> - (void) onExit            callback that is called every time the CCNode leaves the 'stage'. If the CCNode leaves the 'stage' with a
>     transition, this callback is called when the transition finishes.
>     During onExit you can't access a sibling node.

```
X::onExit()
{
getY()->notify_X_Dies(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, you are right. onExit is called when you remove node from it's parent, or when it's parent is removed from the stage/other parent.